# Optimal min hardware configuration for an Orleans silo

Tags: orleans

What is an optimal minimum or recommended hardware (mostly cores-ram) for an orleans silo? for applications having CPU tasks and IO tasks 
and with which criteria orleans decides to scale, adding more nodes in the cloud?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We recommend at least 4 core machines, 8 cores is even before. In terms on memory it mostly depends on your application usage. Orleans itself is pretty modest with its internal memory usage. The general guidelines is to prefer fewer larger machines over more smaller machines.

Orleans does not automatically add new nodes. Thus should be done outside Orleans, via the mechanisns provided by the Cloud provider. Once new nodes are added, Orleans will automatically join them to Orleans cluster and will start utilizing them.

Comment: thanks, I have seen somewhere in configuration=> Scheduler MaxActiveThreads="15", is it corresponds to 8 cores?

Comment: and also, do we need backup node ?

Comment: MaxActiveThreads will default to number of cores automatically and you better not change it. When silo starts it prints its configuration, so you can see what MaxActiveThreads  will be. On 8 cores machine it should be 8.

Comment: Re backups - yes, naturally, you want to run your service on more than 1 node. 3 is usually a good choice. Depending on what Cloud you are using and type of servers, some Cloud provides will auto heal you servers, and automatically start a new one if/when one dies.